# BASH SCRIPT - for image in *** do (Only once - not all pictures all the time) CRON job

Tags: bash, cron

I have a script that watermarks my images using imagemagick. I have setup my script as a bash job, but it watermarks every picture all the time. I wish to exclude pictures already watermarked, but I dont have the options to move all my watermarked pictures out of a certain folder. Folder A contains orginal images. Script scans folder A for png, jpg an gif images, and watermarks them - then moves the original pictures to a subfolder. Each time my script scans folder A, it watermarks all the files that are already watermarked. And I cannot change the names of the files. Is there a way to check the watermarked files by adding them to a filedatabase or something? My script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

 savedir=".originals"

 for image in *png *jpg *gif do  if [ -s $image ] ; then   # non-zero
 file size
     width=$(identify -format %w $image)
     convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center \
        -size ${width}x30 caption:'watermark' \
        $image +swap -gravity south -composite new-$image
      mv -f $image $savedir
      mv -f new-$image $image
     echo "watermarked $image successfully"   fi done
```

Comment: Yes, once watermarked, add a line to a txt file (p.e., _processed.txt_) and then `grep` the filename in this file, if `grep` returns 0, ignore the file, process the file else

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Could you be so kind to show an example of how this could be achieved?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

savedir=".originals"
processed=processed.txt

for image in *png *jpg *gif
do
 if grep -q $image $processed; then   # non-zero file size
    echo "$image is processed before"
    else
    width=$(identify -format %w $image)
    convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center \
       -size ${width}x30 caption:'watermark' \
       $image +swap -gravity south -composite new-$image
     mv -f $image $savedir
     mv -f new-$image $image
    echo "watermarked $image successfully"
    echo $image >> $processed
  fi
`

Comment: I added an example as an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example on how you can modify/update your current script to add a kind of local database file to keep track of the processed files:

```
#!/bin/bash

savedir=".originals"

PROCESSED_FILES=.processed
# This would create the file for the first time if it 
# doesn't exists, thus avoiding "file not found problems" 
touch "$PROCESSED_FILES"

for image in *png *jpg *gif; do 
    # non-zero
    if [ -s $image ]; then  
        # Grep the file from the database
        grep "$image" "$PROCESSED_FILES"

        # Check the result of the previous command ($? is a built-in bash variable 
        # that gives you that), in this case if the result from grep is different
        # than 0, then the file haven't been processed yet
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

            # Process/watermark the file...

            width=$(identify -format %w $image)
            convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x30 caption:'watermark' $image +swap -gravity south -composite new-$image
            mv -f $image $savedir
            mv -f new-$image $image

            echo "watermarked $image successfully"   

            # Append the file name to the list of processed files
            echo "$image" >> "$PROCESSED_FILES"
        fi 
    fi 
done
```

Comment: It really did! That code was ELEGANT and work right out of the box. Thank you soo much!! Perfect

Comment: Glad it helped! Consider accepting/upvoting the answer if you find it useful (also, accepting the answer will give you reputation points)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would prefer not to require some other, external database of names of images I have watermarked - what if that file gets separated from the images, what if they are moved to a different folder hierarchy, or renamed?

My preference would be to set a comment inside the images, that identifies each image as being watermarked, or not - then the information travels around with the image. So, if I watermark an image, I set it in the comment to say so

```
convert image.jpg -set comment "Watermarked" image.[jpg|gif|png]
```

Then, before I watermark, I can check with ImageMagick's `identify` to see if it is done or not:

```
identify -verbose image.jpg | grep "comment:"
Watermarked
```

Obviously, you could be a bit more sophisticated, and extract the current comment and add the "Watermarked" part in without overwriting anything that may already be in there. Or you could set the IPTC author/copyright holder or copyrighted information of the image when you watermark it, and use that as a marker of whether or not the image is watermarked.

Comment: Great idea!  Thanks!  Embedded meta-data makes so much more sense.